# Telerik RadEditor - Text disappears upon entering new content

Tags: html, telerik, radeditor

This editor has given me some serious headache. Here is the HTML that I am generating in the editor.

```html
<p style="text-align: justify;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)]><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align='left'><tr><td align='left' style="padding-right:10px; padding-top:5px;"><![endif]--><img alt="" width="163" height="180" id="img00" style="padding-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px; max-width: 100%; float: left; width: 118px; height: 127px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/Max_Born.jpg/240px-Max_Born.jpg" /><span style="font-family: Verdana;"><img alt="" width="0" height="0" /><!--[if (gte mso 9)]></td><td></tr></table><![endif]-->An atom is the smallest unit of matter. Quantum mechanics is a chapter of physics that studies matter at this incredibly granular level, leading to the invention of personal computers, lasers, and medical imaging devices (MRI), among other game-changing technologies.Today's Doodle celebrates the 135th birthday of Max Born, German physicist and mathematician who was awarded the Nobel Prize for his contribution to the field of quantum mechanics.An outstanding student, Born earned his Ph.D. at G&ouml;ttingen University where he later became a professor of theoretical physics, collaborating with and mentoring some of the most famous scientists of the time.</span></p>
```

The problem here is that when I try to edit the content (in design mode) by typing something, it affects the HTML tag, and the text gets disappeared.
You can reproduce this issue using this link: [Editor Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx). Simply paste the HTML and try to edit the content in design mode.

Is there a way I could prevent this from happening? Thanks

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? I tried to reproduce the problem and it's working as expected. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: In all the browsers :( . If u just try to add a space somewhere in between the text, the entire text gets disappeared, keeping only the image.

Comment: Ah, yep, I was able to reproduce it. I can tell it's the `<!-- [if (gte mso 9)]` directives that are causing the issue. Let me check and see if this is something that's supported by the editor or not.

Comment: I don't see any documentation specific to this. Using mso conditionals directly in content probably isn't the best practice. I would use them at the top level of the document to provide CSS classes to achieve the same results. 

If this is a feature you absolutely need in editor, ex: you're authoring HTML that will be included in email; I would suggest filing a support ticket so engineering can see if there's a plausible solution.

Comment: Thanks Ed for trying this out. Raising support ticket would be the last option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any fix for this. I had to remove those mso conditionals to get things to work as needed.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to disable the ConvertToXhtml content filter and test again: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/builtincontentfilters/defaultcs.aspx

You can also test by disabling other filters too.